# How to build Dockerfile with two jar files

Tags: java, jar, docker, classpath, dockerfile

I'm starting with Docker and I'm a little bit lost.

I have my java experiment with two jar files, zip files with testing data and two configuration files.
And I'm trying to run this exp on Docker.

If I want to run this exp on my pc there are two phases.

Phase 1:

```
java -classpath library.jar;alg.jar library.utl.App.class in.cf
```

where the last parameter is configuration and after this I'll get generated file **alg1.bin**

Phase 2:

```
java -classpath library.jar;alg.jar library.utl.App.class ot.cf
```

where I'm working with file **alg1.bin** and this is main test.

I used Dockerfile for phase 1:

```
FROM java:7

ADD java-exp /usr/local/

CMD ["java", "-classpath",
"/usr/local/library.jar;/usr/local/alg.jar",
"/usr/local/library.utl.App.class", "/usr/local/in.cf"]
```

This I built successfully but when I try

```
docker run java-exp
```

I get an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   .usr.local.library.utl.App.class.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

In the better way, help me merge both two phases into one Dockerfile?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the docker exec -it <container-name> bash and running checking to see if you have everything in the container?

Comment: @ishikun Maybe there is a problem. I did `docker run -d --name exp java-exp` and then `docker exec -it exp bash` and answer is: Error response from daemon: Container exp is not running

Comment: Have you created your docker image called exp yet? type `docker images` and see if 'exp' is there

Comment: @ishikun I created docker image called java-exp: `docker build -t java-exp .`, then I made what I typed in previous comment. And java-exp is in `docker images`.

Comment: Oh okay I see, one more thing you can check is that when you type `docker ps -a` to see if your container named exp is there based on the image java-exp.  Then try `docker logs exp` and see why it didn't start up?

Comment: @ishikun Yes, exp is there and Its based on the image java-exp. After `docker logs exp` I get same error as I typed in my main comment: Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.local.library.utl.App.class. Really don't know why..

Comment: Then that's definitely a java error.  It seems that you're missing something inside the container that you probably already have locally.

Comment: Note that when you're creating anything in Docker that it is a clean slate and you might not have everything you think you should already installed

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
FROM java:7

ADD java-exp /usr/local/

WORKDIR /usr/local/

CMD ["java", "-classpath","library.jar;alg.jar","library.utl.App.class","in.cf"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it.
Main mistake was in CMD

The right thing is:

```
CMD ["java", "-classpath",
"/usr/local/library.jar:/usr/local/alg.jar",
"/usr/local/library.utl.App", "/usr/local/in.cf"]
```

Instead of:

```
CMD ["java", "-classpath",
"/usr/local/library.jar;/usr/local/alg.jar",
"/usr/local/library.utl.App.class", "/usr/local/in.cf"]
```

Two little mistakes :,; and .class

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
CMD ["java", "-cp", "/usr/local/library/*", "/usr/local/library.utl.App.class", "/usr/local/in.cf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you used `ENTRYPOINT` like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/java-exp/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Then in your `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
java -classpath library.jar;alg.jar library.utl.App.class in.cf
java -classpath library.jar;alg.jar library.utl.App.class ot.cf
```